# Text length in php

Tags: php, string-formatting

I have a text and I want to cut this in the end of the line, I don't want a page break, with Arial it's easy to do because all font size is the same, but I'm using a font type where the fonts size is very different, for example i and w. So it's hard to determine the size of the text in the screen,

What is the easiest way to do this, on the server side (php, imagettfbbox) or on the client side (javascript, jQuery)?

Comment: `easiest` --- is there any way to do that on the server?

Comment: imagettfbbox-that give me the size of the string in px

Comment: what if user doesn't have that font?

Comment: arial is *not* monospaced

Comment: http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-autoellipsis

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CSS.

```
white-space:nowrap;
overflow-x:hidden;
width:100px;
```

Comment: I added the width to the answer.